# How override name.phtml file for shipment Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.3.6-p1

I want to add my cusotm code in **`Magento_Sales::items/column/name.phtml`** file
i also created the following XML file

```
sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml,
sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty.xml,
sales_order_creditmemo_view.xml,
sales_order_invoice_new.xml,
sales_order_invoice_updateqty.xml,
sales_order_invoice_view.xml,  
sales_order_view.xml
```

but it's not work for ship
can anybody help me out?

Comment: Please clarify your question. for which purpose you need to override the file and share the whole file location.

Comment: i want to add my custome code in Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\templates\items\column\name.phtml file

Comment: have created any module ?

Comment: You have to create a custom admin theme then you can override admin file under adminhtml theme. You can download admin theme code from https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-backend-theme

Comment: @Mohit Patel Thanks for your reply, Yes i have a created module

Comment: @Mital Shah Thanks for your answer. i override name.phtml file in my custom module and it work's for order and invoice not for ship. so i want to override for ship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override **adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml** file to call custom **name.phtml** file

> app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="column_name">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">
                VendorName_CompanyName::items/column/name.phtml
            </argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Now, Need to create name.phtml file on this below path. You can copy file from **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml** and paste that file on below path. Then, you can add your changes

> app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\templates\items\column\name.phtml

Now, clean cache and check it.

Comment: Thank you @Rohan Hapani. and one thing I read your blog and it is very helpful.

Comment: oh.. Thanks for your appreciation :) Keep sharing.

Comment: @RonakBhatti answer accept is removed?

Comment: Answer is accept.

Comment: Okay. Thanks !! Happy coding !!